# $X,Y$ are r.v.s. $f_{X,Y(x,y)}=ce^{-0.5(3x^2+2xy+2y^2)}$ , $c>0$ is a constant. Find $f_{X|X+Y}(x|1)$

Tags: probability

$X,Y$ are r.v.s.

$f_{X,Y(x,y)}=ce^{-0.5(3x^2+2xy+2y^2)}$ , $c>0$ is a constant.

Find $f_{X|X+Y}(x|1)$

I want to find $f_{X+Y=1}({x,y})$ , then find $f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y(x,y)}dy$

and get $f_{X|X+Y}(x|1)=\frac{f_X}{f_{X+Y=1}}$

SO,

$f_{X+Y=1}(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{1-x}ce^{-0.5(3x^2+2xy+2y^2)}dydx=c\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-0.5(3x^2+2x(1-x)+2(1-x)^2)}}{x-2(1-x)}=c\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-2.5x^2+3x-2}}{3x-2}$

I don't know how to solve it.

Help please

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U = X, V = X + Y$, first find $f_{UV}(u, v)$ using Jacobian Transformation.

Here, $|J| = 1$

So, $ \displaystyle f_{UV} (u, v) = |J| ~f_{XY}(u, v-u) = c \cdot e^{-(3u^2 + 2v^2 - 2 uv)/2}$

$ \displaystyle f_V(v) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{UV}(u, v) ~ du = c \cdot \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{3}} \cdot e^{-5v^2/6}$

Now, $~ \displaystyle f_{U \mid V} (u, 1) = \frac{f_{UV} (u, 1)}{f_{V}(1)}$